# C# Core Interop Attach/Add picture file into a generated Word document

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, interop

I am generating a Word Document using Interop and it is working perfectly fine.

I have a template file and inside that template I have a tag #name#, to which my code passes a value. I am just wondering how do I tweak my code so that it can add a picture as well?

Let's say the image file location is Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "template\image" + ".jpg")
(I would also like to resize that image to a certain dimensions)

```
public FileResult Download()
    {

        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        string TemplateLoc = "template\\Template.docx";
        string path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, TemplateLoc);

        string sourceFile = Path.Combine(path);
        string destinationFile = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "template\\Test" + ".docx");

            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile);

                Dictionary<string, string> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                keyValues.Add("#name#", "Sarah");

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                word.Visible = false;
                word.ScreenUpdating = false;

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Open(destinationFile);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = word.ActiveDocument.Content;

                doc.Activate();

                object missing = Type.Missing;
                object sourceDoc = sourceFile;
                object destinationDoc = destinationFile;
                object matchCase = false;
                object matchWholeWord = true;
                object findWrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
                object findFormat = true;
                object replaceAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
                object fileFormat2 = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument;
                //

                //Replace text ##
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in keyValues)
                {
                    object findText = kvp.Key;
                    object replaceText = kvp.Value;

                    if (range.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord, ref missing,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref findWrap, ref missing,
                        ref replaceText, ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing))
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("Found " + findText + ", replaced with " + replaceText);
                        continue;
                    }
                }


                doc.SaveAs(destinationFile);
                doc.Close();
                word.Quit();


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }


        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "template\\Test" + ".docx"));
        string fileName = "test.docx";
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word has two ways to insert graphics: as Shapes or as InlineShapes. InlineShapes are placed in-line with the text; Shapes have text wrap formatting. The code below shows the syntax for InlineShapes. The syntax for Shapes is very similar and you should get Intellisense if you type `doc.Shapes.AddPicture`. If I have a choice I use an InlineShape because it's placement on the page is more predictable/stable.

No matter which you use it's important to specify the `Range` argument in order to correctly position the graphic.

```
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in keyValues)
            {
                object findText = kvp.Key;
                object replaceText = kvp.Value;

                if (range.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref findWrap, ref missing,
                    ref replaceText, ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Found " + findText + ", replaced with " + replaceText);
                   object oRange = range;
                   object oTrue = true;
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape ils = doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "template\image" + ".jpg"), 
                       ref missing, ref oTrue, ref oRange);
                   ils.Height = 100;
                   ils.Width = 100;

                    //Replace text ##
                    continue;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Sorry late. Just wondering, usually to replace the text, in the template, I have something like #name#. May I know in this case what should I put in the initial template? so that the code know which location to add into?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking? You can certainly use a tag such as #name# and use `Find.Execute` if you wish. It would also be possible to use *bookmarks* as "target markers". If you'd like an example for that, please post a new question.